# Ninject with Task scope

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, ninject

My goal is to resolve new instance from Task in a winforms application.
I read about Task, that is not a thread and write own function to ninject scope

```
    private static Dictionary<string, object> keys = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private static object lockKeyObject = true;
    private static object ContextResolver(Ninject.Activation.IContext context)
    {
        var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CurrentId ?? -1);

        lock (lockKeyObject)
        {
            if (keys.ContainsKey(id) == false)
            {
                keys.Add(id, (object)id);
            }
        }

        return keys[id];
    }
```

and use it as:

```
Bind(typeof(DataClassesDataContext)).To(typeof(DataClassesDataContext))
    .InScope(ContextResolver)
    .WithConstructorArgument<string>(Settings.Default.ConnectionString)
```

Is it right desicion of my problem?

Comment: As far as I know tasks can continue on a different thread. Meaning, your ID combined from ThreadID and Task.CurrentID will change even though it stays the same id.

Comment: I agree with @BatteryBackupUnit the answer is not simple.
Look at this post http://mono.software/2016/04/21/Ninject-ambient-scope-and-deterministic-dispose/ The part "Custom ambient scope and context propagation" seems to be what you need

Comment: @jbl, I read article, but i did not understand about using AmbientScope in Task/Thread. I must write in each Task the construction: using(var scope = new AmbientScope()) { ... }. And also for my project not acceptable in all places insert new AmbientScope(), because in all forms i use: private readonly Class _class = CompositionRoot.Resolve<Class>();

Comment: @Botan If it's not acceptable, the only other alternative is to adapt the "TPL" (custom task scheduler, maybe?) or write your own "TPL" that provides hooks which help you detecting when tasks start etc. It don't think that's any more acceptable so my guess is that, sadly, the only option your left with is to abort your project. Sorry mate.

Comment: Now, seriously, an alternative might be to adapt your design to new require new instances everytime, instead building up the entire application tree on startup and reusing these instances. All temporary data would be moved to data-only types, which do not need to be created by the container.

Comment: @Botan you can write a method which wraps a Task.Run in a new scope and use this method everywhere you start a new task. Also you could rely on factories to delay resolution of your instances (resolving a `Factory<Class>` instead of a Class ), see https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki

Comment: thank you guys, you show me other direction to solve my problem

Comment: Such usage as `CompositionRoot.Resolve` is an anti-pattern named `Service Locator`. The right way to inject your dependencies is to provide them by constructor (or maybe property or method), but not by direct call to `CompositionRoot`